# Updating Google Sheet Field(s) upon form entry

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet containing contact details of my employees. I need particular fields to be updated. (e.g Address Line 1, Address Line 2, City, Postcode) as examples.

Is there a way I can set up a integration between answers from a 'form submission' and the google sheet to update and overwrite the existing data in the related cells? - Without having to manually copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

Your form should store data to a sheet. Use [`importantrange`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340) to import data from that sheet for your applications elsewhere. It will refresh every time you open the sheet with the formula.

It's not upon entry. But you don't seem need to see the change in real time.

Note: for the future, please describe what you desire precisely and **with examples** as well as what you have tried.